# Who applies nuclear force on the nucleons?

Tags: nuclear-physics

My physics teacher told me that whenever we talk about force we need to know who applies the force and on which object the force is applied. If we do not know who applied the force or on which object the force is applied then the force is not real. Instead it is a pseudo force. For example the earth pulls a ball towards itself (gravitational force). Here the force is applied on the ball and the agent who is applying the force is the earth. So gravitational force is a real force. But I am confused as to who applies the nuclear force on the protons and the neutrons inside the nucleus. I know that the force is applied on the nucleons but who applies the force?

Comment: I'm confused why you think the situation between a proton and a neutron is any different from the earth and the ball. Why is "the earth exerts the gravitational force on the ball (and the ball on the earth)" fine for you but "the nucleons exert the nuclear force on each other" apparently not?

Answer (score 1):

The nuclear force *is* the force between the nucleons in the nucleus of an atom, and the cause is another particle called the *pion*.

What your teacher has explained to you is true for forces in the classical macroscopic world. But at the microscopic or quantum realm, forces don’t work in that way. In fact, in the quantum world, we have two main types of elementary particles. [Fermions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermion) which are particles that make up matter, and *[bosons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boson) that are particles which mediate forces between the fermions*. So it is by the *exchange* of bosons that leads to forces at the quantum level.

In the case you mentioned above, as to "who" applies the nuclear force between matter particles, nucleons, the answer is a particle called the [pion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pion)  (which is actually called a pseudo-Goldstone boson). The diagram below also shows the strong force between matter particles called [quarks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark) which are what makes up protons and neutrons (note there are small colored double disks which are gluons that exchange the force between quarks).

[image]

**The force between neutrons and protons inside a nucleus is accomplished by the exchange of pions. This diagram shows this in more detail and the illustration hopefully can help you visualize the exchange process. Remember, that in the quantum world, forces manifest via the exchange of particles.**

[Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pion) is courtesy of Wikipedia.

Comment: I don't know enough about particle physics to judge if your answer is actually correct, but at any rate I think this is answering another question, but not the one OP asked. He doesn't wanna know what mediates the force, his question is more elementary. He wants to know between what and what the force is, or what is exerting a force. See his example with gravitational force, he's not trying to know what conveys the gravitational pull but only what is pulling what. So I think this answer could be very confusing to him. I don't think he needs to know about pseudo-Goldstone bosons for now

Comment: I strongly disagree. There is no other way to explain the force between nucleons without invoking the nuclear force and how/what causes it. I'll add a gif to further illustrate.

Comment: But as far as I can read in his question, OP never asked to explain the nature of the force. Only what is exerting it. Again, I don't criticize the validity of your answer. But it doesn't address the specific question of OP if you read it again. I think there is a valid reason why particle physics is not introduced to students when they are just getting introduced to what a force is

Comment: And what is "exerting" it? Your reasoning is circular.

Comment: Nucleons exert it on each other. Thanks for taking my comments into account in editing your answer. I still personnally think the extra information is gonna be confusing at the level of ripan, but I can agree that your post now includes an answer to his question

Answer (score 1):

Just like the electromagnetic force the nuclear force is exerted by one particle on another.

Answer (score 0):

When we are studying nuclei, the classical mechanics definition of force as $F=ma$ cannot work to describe the data. One has to use the mathematically equivalent $F=mdv/dt$ in order to be compatible with the quantum mechanical frame that is needed for this level.

So the question has to become, "how is  incremental momentum between protons and neutrons transferred"?  The answer by Joseph explains what carries the dp/dt between protons and neutrons,  and the end result of the mathematics is that it is an attractive force , it is called the [strong nuclear force,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_force) and is a spill over from the basic quantum chromodynamic force you may get to learn at university.

It is even more complicated, because in order for a nucleus to be stable the charges of the many protons in the nucleus, which repulse each proton from another, have to be balanced. That is why we get a [periodic table of elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table), not everything can be tied up to everything quantum mechanically.

To answer this:

> But I am confused as to who applies the nuclear force on the protons and the neutrons inside the nucleus

Each proton and neutron applies the nuclear force on each proton and neutron, by, in a simplified  quantum model, exchanging the pions which carry the $dp/dt$

Comment: Anna. You need to replace your first  mdp/dt with an mdv/dt. It also seems  like you are mixing classical descriptions with quantum ones.

Comment: @josephh thanks ,or take the m away.

Comment: no worries Anna.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to provide a concise answer, stressing a point that I think is important to complement the previous good answers.

The concept of force is deeply rooted in classical mechanics. However, due to their very short range, nuclear forces do not play a role at the macroscopic level. At the microscopic level, we need quantum mechanics. But in quantum mechanics, there is no room for the Newtonian concept of force. Dynamics is controlled by the interaction energies. It is not only a matter of using a potential energy function in the place of its space derivatives. Using potential energies embodies in a much deeper way than Newtonian dynamics the idea that interactions are properties *of the system*. Newtonian dynamics has to introduce the third law to stress the mutual character of the forces. Interactions at the quantum level encode from the beginning the idea that **if particle/field A interacts with particle/field B, also B interacts with A**.

One could say that it is just a misnaming to speak about nuclear *forces* instead of *interactions*.